# Can I use py.test to test the Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I have a Flask application which uses `py.test` for testing. But some things are not properly covered by usual unittests.

For example, if my `requirements.txt` contains all necessary modules. Or if the `Dockerfile` installs all necessary binaries.

**Is it possible to cover those error sources with `py.test`?**

(For example, can I run `docker build` and test if that works? - This takes long, can I have `py.test --long` for all and `py.test` for the fast tests only?)

Comment: I just found https://nvbn.github.io/2015/09/09/pytest-docker/ - that might be what I'm looking for.